# How to configure Hibernate Cfg file for Tomcat Server

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat, cpanel

**Problem:- My web site is running on localhost normally but when i deploy my war file, website works for a day only. After that i have to reload an application from Tomcat Manager.**

I'm trying to configure my hibernate.cfg.xml file for server. In that i have been used common-pool jar files as well as some hibernate configuration properties i tried to figure out by using lot's of solutions but I'm not getting correct solution.Below is my Hibernate configuration file.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name?autoReconnect=true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">database_username</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">database_password</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLMyISAMDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">0</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">75</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

<property name="hibernate.dbcp.initialSize">0</property>
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxActive">-1</property>
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle">75</property>
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.minIdle">25</property>
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxConnLifetimeMillis">-1</property>
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxWaitMillis">-1</property>
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis">1800000</property>
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis">-1</property>
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.testWhileIdle">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.testOnReturn">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.validationQuery">SELECT 1</property>
```

Here is my Stacktrace

```
    Exception: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2216)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
    at com.estate.model.PostPropertyService.searchAllResidentialCategory(PostPropertyService.java:39)
    at org.apache.jsp.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:167)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: Broken pipe

STACKTRACE:

java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:2708)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1604)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1715)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3249)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1268)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1403)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2213)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
    at com.estate.model.PostPropertyService.searchAllResidentialCategory(PostPropertyService.java:39)
    at org.apache.jsp.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:167)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **



Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:2723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1604)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1715)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3249)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1268)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1403)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2213)
```

Please suggest me a corrections or solution.

Thanking You,
Akshay D Shete